# OnTriggerEnter error: The message parameter has to be of type: Collider

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics

I have a crate and I want to make it so if you are in the trigger of the crate a UI appears and says "Click E to loot".

I have the UI setup but the script is not working. Here is my script and after it are the errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UI_Appear : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image image;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            image.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            image.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors say:

> Script Error: OnTriggerEnter
> The message parameter has to be of type: Collider
>
> Script Error: OnTriggerExit
> The message parameter has to be of type: Collider

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message tells you exactly what's wrong: when you implement the `OnTriggerEnter` message, Unity expects the parameter to be of type `Collider`.

But the way you wrote your `OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)`, its parameter is of type `Collider2D`.

These are completely unrelated types - one is from the 3D physics system using PhysX, the other is from the 2D physics system using Box2D.

If you want 2D physics, you need to use the 2D versions of these message functions, as shown in recent answers to your questions:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also added a on start the image is false because it was showing itself on start. Do you know how to make is so when I click E in the trigger the crate destroys itself? I just dont know how to only let it work when in trigger.

Comment: Did you consider storing a boolean variable when something enters the trigger, and clearing it when it leaves?